# Robocopy: "The system cannot find the path specified." for cell phone micro SD card

Tags: robocopy, micro-sd-card

I am trying to expand the memory in my Samsung Galaxy S8 by copying over the current data in my micro SD card to a larger one. Unfortunately, I don't have a micro SD slot on my computer, so I want to connect the phone to my computer via USB, copy the files to the computer, and paste them into the new micro SD card once it is in the phone. However, the default copying behavior with Windows Explorer brings up the "calculating time" window, which I want to avoid.

I read that robocopy can bypass this, but this does not work for me because the source directory is "This PC\SAMSUNG-SM-G930A\Card" and command prompt gives me this message:

"2017/11/27 21:46:38 ERROR 3 (0x00000003) Accessing Source Directory C:\WINDOWS\system32\This PC\SAMSUNG-SM-G930A\Card\
The system cannot find the path specified."

Is there a way around this?

Comment: I think you may need to change the Phone Behaviour when plugged into the USB. Some phone can act as a Mass Data Storage (or USB disk) instead of using the usual connection. Also you may get better answer in android.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is the way the system maps and hides the device. If you search in the folder, the search address bar will have the physical path used if I remember correctly and that is what you can then use in command prompt.